# need something that automatically press keys (e.g. 'Y' or 'Win+Ctrl+Y') when detect a file in a folder or a link

Tags: windows-11, hotkeys

I'm trying to create a notifier that advise you when a new song is playing in Spotify (like the PS4/PS5 default one) using Rainmeter and JaxCore, (I'm on Windows 11).
I've already set it up but I have to make it pops-out when the songs change and I've no idea of how doing that. it manually pops-out by pressing Win+Ctrl+Y (I can change the key if I want), so I thought about something that automatically presses Win+Ctrl+Y, so I could make it pops-out. now I can't find any solutions about linking that automatic-key-press action to the change of songs. there's a folder where the current artwork is stored and, when songs change, it also changes but the file name is always the same. I included 'or a link' in the title because if it's possible to do that also by monitoring webpages it could be another solution (checking 'https://open.spotify.com/oembed?url= + song url').
can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Check out https://www.autohotkey.com/.  Can detect application windows and perform custom actions.